# Ordered repeated tuples enumerate asymptotics

Tags: combinatorics

Given integer $n$ and vector length $m$ how many ordered non negative integer vectors of length $m$ we can have such that every entry is bound by $n$ and repeated entries are allowed?

Comment: Do you mean this: $$|\{(x_1,\cdots ,x_m):0\leq x_i\leq n\}|?$$ If so, the answer is $(n+1)^m$

Comment: xi<=xi also holds.

Comment: Sorry but no idea what you mean by that.